# SwiftUI: Doing math in the body

Tags: swiftui

I am fetching data from a Core Data store and displaying it in this view. One of these values is an integer 'duration'. I would like to display the sum of all fetched 'duration' values in the NavigaationBarTitle. But the line 'totalDuration += event.eventDuration' in the code below invokes the build-time error: '*The compiler is unable to type check this expression in a reasonable time....*'. Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData


struct AdminEventsLog: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Event.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Event.eventDate, ascending: true)]) var events: FetchedResults<Event>
    
    var dateFormatter: DateFormatter{
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        return formatter
    }

    @State var showEventLogging = false
    @State var totalHours: Int16 = 0
    var totalDuration: Int16 = 0
    

    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(events){ event in
                let duration = convertDuration(duration: event.eventDuration) //Converts the int
                totalDuration += event.eventDuration
                
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                        Text("Date: ")
                            .bold()
                            + Text("\(self.dateFormatter.string(from: event.eventDate!))")
                        + (Text(" Details: "))
                            .bold()
                            + Text("\(event.eventDetails!)")
                        + Text(" Dur: ").bold()
                            + Text("\(duration)")
                            + Text(" hrs:min")
                    }
                    HStack{
                        Text(" Category: ").bold()
                            + Text("\(event.eventCategory!)")
                    }
                }.font(.footnote)
            }
            .onDelete{ indexSet in
                for index in indexSet{
                    self.managedObjectContext.delete(self.events[index])
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Log: \(convertDuration(duration: totalHours))")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
            self.showEventLogging = true
            print("Open ordersheet")
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                })).sheet(isPresented: $showEventLogging){
                    EnterEvent().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.managedObjectContext)
        }
        
    }
}

struct AdminEventsLog_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        return AdminEventsLog().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ForEach` View isn't the same as a for each loop.

Calculate the total not in the body property, but with another computed property, from the data you have:

```
var totalDuration: Int {
   events.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.eventDuration })
}
```

Then you could use it in the View:

```
var body: some View {
   // ...

   Text("\(totalDuration)")

   // ...
}
```